# How to call a function multiple times on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
for (var i = 0; i < malls.length; i++) {
  mall = malls[i];
  codeAddress(mall);
}

$scope.codeAddress = function(mall){}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
  <button class="button" ng-click="codeAddress()">
    Find Me
  </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
```

hi, when i call a function in my loop i get this message :
ReferenceError: codeAddress is not defined

Comment: where is your `codeAddress()` function definition?

Comment: do you want to call `codeAddress()` multiple times on button click?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `$scope`:

```
$scope.codeAddress = function(mall){} // add this above the loop

for (var i = 0; i < malls.length; i++) {
     mall = malls[i];
     $scope.codeAddress(mall);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rfn8m98n/) example.

Comment: not work , i get again this message :$scope.codeAddress is not a function

Comment: Its because your codeAddress method is below the loop. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval to loop a funtion with a time parameter

```
var counter = 0;
 var i = setInterval(function(){
// do your thing
Somefunctionyouwanttoloop()
counter++;
if(counter === 10) {
    clearInterval(i);
}
}, 200);
```